# SQL double relationship beetween two tables

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, composite

I'm trying to develope a multiple relationship between two areas of my project, the first is Ebooks and the second is News.

The thing is one ebook can have a many-to-many relationship to news and news can also have a many-to-many relantionship.

Right now i'm working with one relationship table for each case so i have one table called Ebooks_News and another one News_Ebooks. The problem is i have around 7 of these areas to create these relations, so at the end i'm going to have 14 relationship tables.

Is there any other way to make this work ?

**EDIT:**

Would i have some performance impact if i keep the actual structure ? I intend to consume this data using EF from .NET.

**EDIT 2:**

Would it be possible to achieve what i want using composite ? Could anyone provide me with an example if possible ? I'm using this structure with DB First and EF in C#.

Comment: Would it work to have one many-to-many table with a type field indicating which relationship type it is?  It sounds like that way you could just have one many-to-many table.

Comment: You could create a common base table (think abstraction) for each of your 7 areas with fewer association tables.

Comment: @Rono, that would also work but in my opinion it wouldn't be much better than what i have right now and i would have to add one more verification on each Update, Delete and Select

Comment: @Biscuits, how would i manage that, i could really get the idea

Comment: Suppose that EBooks and News each also referenced their own records in a new table (perhaps Article). One could then link Articles to Articles (or other things, for that matter). Thus, EBooks and News would be considered a specialization of Article.

Comment: Ok, now i get it but it wouldn't work...they are really distinct, Rono's idea sound nice but for me i don't think it's worth since i already have most of the tables created already....my other worry is that this amount of tables i have in some way would make my queries slower, would that happen ? I'm gonna work with EF to consume this data

Comment: Using more tables is not necessarily a bad thing. In fact, it is generally a good thing. If there's no compelling reason to use one table, I would use separate tables for sure.

Comment: Great, thanks for it buddy for now i'm going to keep it like that but your idea is nice...might use it in some other project. Thank you too Rono